# How important Ruby background is for using Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I am working on choosing and adopting a static site generator.

My understanding is that Jekyll is the most popular one. I learned that Jekyll is based on Ruby language.

I do not have any experience with Ruby and it is not on my Career path. I am very much a .NET and C# developer.

Do I need to know Ruby in order to use Jekyll **efficiently**? Or should I compromise and adopt a less popular static site generator that is based on .NET platform?

**Update after having good answers here and some research**

I think we have good response and answers here. Thank you @2583rk and  @deveth0

However, I am discouraged by the fact that Jekyll disregards Windows and does not provide official support for it. Windows is quite a popular desktop OS and ignoring it does not look good for a tool that usually (and practically) runs on a "non-server" or desktop environment (It does generates files run on servers though)

I am going to give  [Pretzel](https://www.staticgen.com/pretzel) a try as it has all the benefits of Jekyll plus more.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask] or the [tour].

Comment: @risingDarkness, thank you for the heads up. Can you give me a hint how to improve this question?

Comment: Just a clarification: the Jekyll engine is **implemented** using Ruby, but unless you have some plan on developing a plugin for Jekyll you won't see any line of Ruby when **using** Jekyll. What you need to know is the [liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) template language: that's what you will use when using Jekyll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my blog over to Jekyll earlier this year with no background in Ruby and, for the most part, it hasn't been a problem. Jekyll is a simple and straightforward solution with some good documentation; you can find a lot of examples online on how to setup it up properly and use plugins without knowing too much about Ruby.

I've been using Jekyll on a Windows laptop without any issues. There's a separate set of instructions for getting it up and running on Windows [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/#installation). You need to install a package manager called [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), then install ruby using `choco install ruby -y` and then you can install Jekyll using `gem install jekyll`. There's some more detailed information on the link for specific things like encoding, auto-generation, etc.

Comment: Here's a link I found helpful when I first started using Jekyll: [Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for Ruby understanding. Most task just require a basic or deeper knowledge of markdown and liquid, but both are easy to learn. 
Only if you want to build plugins, you'll need Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for help. To my understanding, Jekyll is not officially supported on Windows. Is that correct? If that is true, I think I am going to find a more windows friendly option.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll works fine on Windows. Half my doc team is using Jekyll with Windows. Here's a [tutorial on installing Jekyll on Windows](http://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_install_jekyll_on_windows.html).